# Recommend a cross platform like Klok for time tracking

Tags: time-management

Love Klok but it's dependence platform, Adobe AIR, appears not to be as well supported as it used to be - specifically for Linux.

Are there similar tools out there?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.